# Word VBA String insertion with special characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

code segment

```
String1 = "the quick brown" & " fox " &  "jumped over..."
With wdoc.Tables(pos)
   .Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Text = String1
End with
```

OK Simple enough - assign string and then assign string to cell.

What I would like to do is tell the word " fox " he is bold.  Can this be done?  Is there a special character sequence?  for example ^B, does anyone know where the complete list can be found?  The text can obviously be anything...

thanks and regards
Seán

Comment: Not sure if you can do that using variable (they contain only text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose only a workaround for what you need- as far as I know there isn't any simple solution for such a thing. Please see some comments and explanation inside the code.

```
'put each part of your text into array,
'No white-spaces inside quotation marks
String1 = Array("the quick brown", "fox", "jumped over...")

'let's change With structure a bit:
With wDoc.Tables(pos).Rows(1).Cells(1)

    'put text to table as a result of Joining all array elements
   .Range.Text = Join(String1, " ")

   'assuming you want to bold 2nd element of your text/array which ever long it is
   'we search range within document which refers to this part of our text
   'which could be done in this way:
   wDoc.Range( _
                .Range.Start + Len(String1(0)), _
                .Range.Start + Len(String1(0)) + Len(String1(1)) + 1). _
                Font.Bold = True

End With
```

and the result looks as presented below:

[image]